# vega JSON Gantt Chart Scroll

Tags: powerbi, vega, deneb

[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr0gu.png)

[today screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MR4P.png)

I used deneb in power bi to create a Gantt chart with vega JSON.

The first screen is the first launch screen.

When I run the Gantt chart, I want to position the scroll to where the current date is directly visible.

Is this possible?

English may not be smooth because you're using a translator.
We apologize in advance.

I've tried to find a way to adjust the scroll or change the position with Vega JSON, but it doesn't seem to support that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This sample opens to a specified point on a line:
[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegM5QHsBjAa1wDojcA3EAXwBoQB3ASzCgAt4BGABgFNOAU1YBzTlHgBWQSFQQAnsOTwA2qGEA7IgTCstY+KAAexkADNWw1GAyQowkEyiKADk7ghHAWzcFkCHRGEEVzKxs7LzdkViInF3dPEABHRAgtKFYYLOonEN1UAPDrWwxcRR8AIwJ0RI8MLQIfAyD6EIVlVTgNEB8IZBIMVAN8hlA3AYgfXHVQLWnkhSqbZxBqIMRPXrMEUOEB+AAmAQB2Jh8CTO44fjo6AF0mXBthIik91wboggMpJm0un0hlmPRAZieIC0B2Qwnw8CgyC2TCuGEuiBeBDyqnukP6gww-j+a0BegMRj2BEmRGyYT2ui0+iyqL2k0CPmGEBWdRAwj8rngFiCLyYG1QW14ITFErgfHuj0YoERGVwFgCHJ6oCsqEc3QmUw18i5qwB-LpQtQL1xTE6KjmfQGQ0+SQwSNQCRAhWKXjEgTCIVJwIppnMX2Svn8gR5ETKXgcHogYl9wjE0GSLS07UVvJ0ZMMoeEJg+SpdXjSGSyOVYeTWMaiIBicTG4NDpe8fMjbSYdfsabWlfdGAAIn2QnSS99UulMtloNWPT3orF4v3soOvAAFZf5DpKO2ah0E52TxxFtb4ZAEEjJZicbIei9X4QAdXYXGOTCC4kzXndFn+4C7NITBgHSAC0wGWFcUAAMqsAAXp4RwACz3OMh5OhO4aFgBX5iD+8jCP+axgEBIHgZBaqZHBiHHKhAK5kG5henq3htk0GZdpYpT1hU1S1FmDwKkJQA)

Here's the key bit of code:

```
        {"mark": "line"},
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "label",
              "value": [
                {
                  "x": {
                    "year": 2007,
                    "month": 10
                  }
                }
              ],
              "select": {
                "type": "point",
                "encodings": ["x"],
                "nearest": true,
                "on": "mouseover"
              }
            }
          ],
```